# The step by step actions which occur as a result of the return operator, inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am new learning the fundamentals. I have looked at many questions on here and youtube, and even on my udemy lecture. But none answer my question.
To be clear, my question is NOT how to use the return operator. I can use it perfectly well. The question is more to do with HOW it works, and what is actually happening in detail.

And please don't say *"So in short, when we return something from a function, we are actually returning it from a function."* - because this was one of the explainations I got before, and it does not explain anything to me hahaha :)

Here is the example code for this question:

```js
function example(digit1, digit2) {
  const sum = digit1 + digit2;
  return `${sum}`
}
const invoke = example(1, 2);
console.log(invoke);
```

I think the best way to answer this question is to give me a step by step list of the journey that 'sum' makes. From the moment it is written, to the end of the whole code.
The return operator is clearly moving 'sum', as the word 'return' can only mean this, by definition.

When I read this code I see that 'sum' is inside the curly braces off the function, and then directly after this 'sum' is then RETURNED (to the place which it started). Now as 'sum' has not gone anywhere, returning it (to the place which it started) is REDUNDANT.

when the function is invoked there must be some kind of journey happening which I do not understand.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: In your code, the `return` will always return the *string value* `"sum"`.

Comment: Thank you Pointy, I've edited corrected the code *facepalm*

Comment: It might help to think about how things like `sin()` and `cos()` work in math. An angle measurement is provided, and `sin()` returns a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I read this code I see that 'sum' is inside the curly braces off the function, and then directly after this 'sum' is then RETURNED (to the place which it started). Now as 'sum' has not gone anywhere, returning it (to the place which it started) is REDUNDANT.

Nope. You're misinterpreting what's "returning" and where it's being returned to.

The function is returning the value contained in `sum` to whatever *called* the function, not to "the place where it (`sum`) started".

```
function example(digit1, digit2) {
  const sum = digit1 + digit2;
  return `${sum}`
}
const invoke = example(1, 2);
console.log(invoke);
```

The function `example` receives two values which it places in the variables `digit1` and `digit2`, then creates a new variable `sum` which contains the result of adding `digit1` and `digit2`.  (The variables `digit1`, `digit2`, and `sum` are all scoped to the function itself; they do not exist outside of that function.) It then returns the value contained in `sum` -- *not* the variable itself -- to the thing that called the function.

Which in this case, is this line:

`const invoke = example(1, 2)`

The function `example` receives the values 1 and 2, and returns the value "3".  Which means that outside the function, the returned value takes the place of the function call itself, resulting in, effectively,

`const invoke = "3"`

The code outside the function "calls" the function. The function "returns" a value -- not a variable, a value! -- to the code outside the function.   You can think of a function as a box with inputs and an output: you call it with inputs, and it returns to you an output value.

(Incidentally, the return statement you've used unnecessarily coerces the result into a string, where you probably want a number: just `return sum` would likely be preferable.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I now understand how something is being returned, and not just sent. So this follows the premise in (english language) of "They were called, and in return they sent a gift", rather than how I was imagining it: "Return my wallet to me, theif!". Before, the only way I could fathom what was happening was to assume that return was like an assignment operator, which assigns the 'sum' to 'example', like storing things inside a variable. While this mentality works, I knew it was wrong. Thanks again, I can continue coding without being peeved haha :)

Comment: No worries!  This was an interesting one to answer; some concepts get so engrained by habit that it can be difficult to explain them to people who don't already understand them -- which is how you wind up with stuff like "when we return something from a function, we are actually returning it from a function" :)

Comment: @Codewell it's good to ask questions like this, because it's often the case that people learning something complicated like programming make *one wrong turn* that leads to all sorts of confusion. The ability to recognize, pinpoint even, a conceptual gap is very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

`return` will put whats being returned (`sum` in this case) at the place where the function is invoked (in this case, in front of `invoke`).
so `invoke` = `sum` (`sum` is returned/ put on the place where the function is invoked)

Comment: *Return statements in many languages allow a function to specify a return value to be passed back to the code that called the function.* from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement)

Comment: @Codewell the term `return` or `returns` has been in use in computing to refer to what happens when a  function produces a value for about 60 years now.